# Python - Can I create a zip file inside the very folder I am zipping?

Tags: python

I am trying to archive all the files in a folder, inside a zip folder; although when I create the zip folder, it is actually create outside the folder it is zipping, while I would like to have both the files and the zip file inside the folder.

This is what I am using:

```
import shutil

output_filename = "testfile"
dir_name = "Users/owner/Desktop/misc/"

shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)
```

This end up generating a zip file but it is created outside the `misc` folder, while I would like to have the zip file inside the `misc` folder. Is this not possible because otherwise the zip function would continue to zip itself, since the process is recursive?

Comment: Have you tried changing `output_filename` to `"Users/owner/Desktop/misc/testfile"`?

Comment: You can add the path to output_filename but you may end up zipping the zip file. Another option is to just move it when you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I did not try to add the full path, because I thought that doing so would end up in recursive zip; which seems to be a possibility, from what tdelaney said. I will just move it afterward; thanks!